# Load onClick event to all body tags from a separate JS file

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am working on a Visio project that I am going to export to HTML and I would like to add an onClick event to the auto generated separate JS file that loads the "onClick" function to the `<body>` tags on all pages.

Basically, change the one JS file to have the "onClick" event to be attached to all `<body>` tags in the multiple pages (50+) that will be created when I export.

Rather than edit very page to add `onclick="handleEvent(event)"` to every `<body>` tag, I'd like to do it once in the JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.body.addEventListener` and add your function as a callback:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", handleEvent);
```

For this to work how you want, you need to put this in a single js file and you need to have that file included in all of your pages.

You can read more on how to add event listeners [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but couldn't you add an event listener with a callback function for the body each body tag. To set each even listener use a for loop to go through the array of Body tags ??
Sorry for bad english

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var i = 0;
for(i;i<x.length;i++){
x[i].addEventListener("click","myfunction",false);
}
```